# datepicker and datetimepicker EU format?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm trying to implement the jquery
datepicker and datetimepicker into 1 script 
but standard the date is US formatted. (should be DD-MM-YY)
I cannot get the javascriptcode working, what's wrong?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" > 
  $(document).ready(function() {

    function tijd(){ 
    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
        timeFormat: 'h:m', 
        stepHour: 1,
        stepMinute: 15
        });
    }
    function datum(){ 
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' 
        });
    }
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a date like "07-09-11" try something like

```
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-y'
```

if your looking for a date like "7-9-11" then then try,

```
dateFormat: 'd-m-y'
```

But whatever the format your looking for your going to need to use the formats listed here:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

And if you want to customize the dates look you might do something like

```
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            create: function (input, inst) {
                var datestr = $(this).val();
                var month = datestr.substring(0, datestr.indexOf("/")) - 1;
                var temp = datestr.substring(datestr.indexOf("/") + 1, datestr.length);
                var year = temp.substring(temp.indexOf("/") + 1, temp.indexOf("/") + 5);
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            }
```

This gives you MONTH YEAR like "SEPTEMBER 2011"

But my guess is you have too many 'y' in your format.